# PDO, How to display data in the dropdown list?

Tags: php, pdo

In my edit form, I'd like to display the names of employees which I can select who will do the user's requests, but when I have tried to display it, it only showed me one name of the employee, and I put the while statement for fetching the data and it showed me 2 edit forms which has different value of dropdown list (the first edit form showed me Employee A, and the second one showed me Employee B), how can I display the Employee A and Employee B names in the same dropdown list and in the same form? here's my code so far :

```
      <?php
      $page_number = $_GET['page'];
      $dbdit = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=laundry','root','');
      $results = $dbdit->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM konsumen");
      $results->execute();
      $get_total_rows = $results->fetch();
      $results = $dbdit->prepare("SELECT * FROM konsumen ORDER BY kode_pemesanan ASC LIMIT $page_number");
      $resultkaryawan = $dbdit->prepare("SELECT * FROM karyawan");
      $results->execute();
      $resultkaryawan->execute();
      $row = $results->fetch();
      while($data = $resultkaryawan->fetch()){


      print_r("<table align='center' >
            <form method='POST' action='save.php' align='center'>
            <tr>
            <td>Kode Pemesanan</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='kode_pemesanan' value='".$row['kode_pemesanan']."'  class='inputnomor' disabled></td>
            <tr>
            <td>Atas Nama</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='atas_nama' value='".$row['atas_nama']."'  class='inputnomor' disabled></td>
            <tr>
            <td>Jumlah Baju</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input name='jumlahBaju' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahbaju' value='".$row['jmlhbaju']."' min='0' onChange='calcBaju()'> Rp.3500,00-/pcs <input name='totalBaju' type='number' class ='total' id='totalbaju' value='".$row['jmlhbaju'] * 3500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcBaju()'></td>
            <tr>
            <td>Jumlah Celana</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input name='jumlahCelana' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahCelana' value='".$row['jmlhcelana']."' min='0' onChange='calcCelana()'> Rp.2500,00-/pcs <input name='totalCelana' type='number' class ='total' id='totalcelana' value='".$row['jmlhcelana'] * 2500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcCelana()'></td>

            <tr>
            <td>Jumlah Jaket</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input name='jumlahJaket' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahjaket' value='".$row['jmlhjaket']."' min='0' onChange='calcJaket()'> Rp.6500,00-/pcs <input name='totalJaket' type='number' class ='total' id='totaljaket' value='".$row['jmlhjaket'] * 6500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcJaket()'></td>

            <tr>
            <td>Jumlah Jas</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input name='jumlahJas' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahjas' value='".$row['jmlhjas']."' min='0' onChange='calcJas()'> Rp.8500,00-/pcs <input name='totalJas' type='number' class ='total' id='totaljas' value='".$row['jmlhjas'] * 8500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcJas()'></td>
            <tr>
            <td>Jumlah Dress</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input name='jumlahDress' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahdress' value='".$row['jmlhdress']."' min='0' onChange='calcDress()'> Rp.7500,00-/pcs <input name='totalDress' type='number' class ='total' id='totaldress' value='".$row['jmlhdress'] * 7500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcDress()'></td>
            <tr>
            <td>Status Pesanan</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type='radio' name='status_pesanan' value='sedangproses'>Sedang di Proses<input type='radio' name='status_pesanan' value='sudahselesai'>Sudah Selesai
            </td>
            <tr>
            <td>Pengurus Pesanan</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><select>
                <option value=''>>-----SELECT-----<</option>
                <option value=''>". $data['nm_karyawan'] ."</option>


                </select>
            </td>

             </form>
             </table>
             ");    
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: i also tried to put the while statement after the <option value=''>". and before the $data['nm_karyawan'] but it showed me error in my editor software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only fetching the first dataset of the result. Use fetchAll()

```
$data = $resultkaryawan->fetchAll()
```

Your loop is on the wrong place. I think you only want to iterate over $data to fill your . So you should do it like this:

```
<select>
   <option value=''>>-----SELECT-----<</option>
<?php while($data = $resultkaryawan->fetchAll()){ ?>
   <option value=''><?= $data['nm_karyawan'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

thoough, you would have to structure your code otherwise to output the html. But this is an example where to put the loop.

To output your html you could do it like this:

```
  $page_number = $_GET['page'];
  $dbdit = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=laundry','root','');
  $results = $dbdit->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM konsumen");
  $results->execute();
  $get_total_rows = $results->fetch();
  $results = $dbdit->prepare("SELECT * FROM konsumen ORDER BY kode_pemesanan ASC LIMIT $page_number");
  $resultkaryawan = $dbdit->prepare("SELECT * FROM karyawan");
  $results->execute();
  $resultkaryawan->execute();
  $row = $results->fetch();
?>
      <table align='center' >
        <form method='POST' action='save.php' align='center'>
        <tr>
        <td>Kode Pemesanan</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='kode_pemesanan' value='<?= $row['kode_pemesanan'] ?>'  class='inputnomor' disabled></td>
        <tr>
        <td>Atas Nama</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='atas_nama' value='<?= $row['atas_nama'] ?>'  class='inputnomor' disabled></td>
        <tr>
        <td>Jumlah Baju</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name='jumlahBaju' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahbaju' value='<?= $row['jmlhbaju'] ?>' min='0' onChange='calcBaju()'> Rp.3500,00-/pcs <input name='totalBaju' type='number' class ='total' id='totalbaju' value='".$row['jmlhbaju'] * 3500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcBaju()'></td>
        <tr>
        <td>Jumlah Celana</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name='jumlahCelana' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahCelana' value='".$row['jmlhcelana']."' min='0' onChange='calcCelana()'> Rp.2500,00-/pcs <input name='totalCelana' type='number' class ='total' id='totalcelana' value='".$row['jmlhcelana'] * 2500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcCelana()'></td>

        <tr>
        <td>Jumlah Jaket</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name='jumlahJaket' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahjaket' value='".$row['jmlhjaket']."' min='0' onChange='calcJaket()'> Rp.6500,00-/pcs <input name='totalJaket' type='number' class ='total' id='totaljaket' value='".$row['jmlhjaket'] * 6500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcJaket()'></td>

        <tr>
        <td>Jumlah Jas</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name='jumlahJas' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahjas' value='".$row['jmlhjas']."' min='0' onChange='calcJas()'> Rp.8500,00-/pcs <input name='totalJas' type='number' class ='total' id='totaljas' value='".$row['jmlhjas'] * 8500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcJas()'></td>
        <tr>
        <td>Jumlah Dress</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name='jumlahDress' type='number' class='inputpemesanan' id='jumlahdress' value='".$row['jmlhdress']."' min='0' onChange='calcDress()'> Rp.7500,00-/pcs <input name='totalDress' type='number' class ='total' id='totaldress' value='".$row['jmlhdress'] * 7500 . "' min='0' disabled onChange='calcDress()'></td>
        <tr>
        <td>Status Pesanan</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='status_pesanan' value='sedangproses'>Sedang di Proses<input type='radio' name='status_pesanan' value='sudahselesai'>Sudah Selesai
        </td>
        <tr>
        <td>Pengurus Pesanan</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>
            <select>
               <option value=''>>-----SELECT-----<</option>
            <?php while($data = $resultkaryawan->fetchAll()){ ?>
               <option value=''><?= $data['nm_karyawan'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </td>

         </form>
         </table>
```

It's quite a lot of html so I was too lazy to fill in your php with the $row-values, you will have to do it yourself. Basicaly you have to switch

```
".$row['jmlhcelana']."
```

to

```
<?= $row['jmlhcelana'] ?>
```

Comment: thank you it solve my multiple forms come out, but still it only showed me 1 employee name, can't get another employee names

Comment: Yes, I edited. Your loop is in the wrong place so you build a new form for every iteration.

Comment: yes i tried it before, but it showed me syntax error after i put the php code after the <option> tag,

Comment: Because you are inside the print_r();. Easiest way would be to output it directly by just leaving the php-scope and opening it again when starting the loop. Gonny edit my post

Comment: so we can't put the php code inside the print_r();?

Comment: Correct. above you can see one way to solve your problem. Another one would be to first put the html into a variable by concatenating the different strings, after that you could use echo or print to display your html. I think this way is, in this case, better because it is more readable when syntax-highlighting of the editor or ide comes into play.

Comment: thank you so much philipp!! now it can display the employee names, btw it won't work when using fetchAll(); so i change it into fetch(); :)

Comment: just for ask, what does the ' = ' symbol works in <?=  ?

Comment: <?= ?> is the short tag for echo. Since version 5.4 it is by default enabled, quite handy in situations like these. You're right, fetchAll() doesn't work with while :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  while($row = $results->fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
  }
```